# pcap_if_t : how to pick an element from this structure

Tags: c, pcap, libpcap

: 
The result of pcap_findalldevs function :

Finding available devices ...

```
 1:eth0 -- (null)
 2:wlan0 -- (null)
 3:nflog -- Linux netfilter log (NFLOG) interface
 4:any -- Pseudo-device that captures on all interfaces
 5:lo -- (null)
```

I want to select wlan0. How can I do it ?

Thanks in advance
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Did you see the man pages for pcap? You can pass an interface name to any of [`pcap_create`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pcap_create/) or [`pcap_open_live`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pcap_open_live/). The interface name is in the `name` member of the `pcap_if_t`.

Comment: I did, actually I use 
if(device->next->name == "wlan0") with device is (pcap_if_t) struct
// then process to display the device for example 
but nothing is hapening.

Comment: You can just do `pcap_create("wlan0", ...);`. No need for the `pcap_if_t` if you already know the interface name.

Comment: OK thanks nneonneo even if I preferred to select the device I want from the list of devices.  
I have a question wich has to do with JNetPcap for capturing packet with Java, and I need to run my testpcap.java with root privileges as I found in forums but I don't know how to process it. how could I run my application as I can do with the C programm (using sudo command ) could youtell me more about it ? thanks in advance

Comment: That's an entirely separate question.

Comment: Yes I know and I'm wondering if someone could help on finding the solution ?